# flatMap vs map, basic explanation is ok, but what happens when my transformation function isn't synchronous by itself?

Tags: project-reactor

I like basic explanations of complex concepts in reactor all over the web, they are not particularly useful in production code, so following piece of code I wrote which sends a message to kafka using reactor kafka + spring boot:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderResult;

import java.util.Properties;

public class CallbackSender {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private String topic;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CallbackSender.class.getName());

    private final KafkaSender<String, String> sender;

    public CallbackSender(ObjectMapper objectMapper, Properties senderProps, String topic) {
        this.sender = KafkaSender.create(SenderOptions.create(senderProps));
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public Mono<SenderResult<String>> sendMessage(ProcessContext<? extends AbstractMessage> processContext) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                                                                             objectMapper.writeValueAsString(processContext.getMessage()));

        SenderRecord<String, String, String> senderRecord = SenderRecord.create(producerRecord, processContext.getId());

        return sender.send(Flux.just(senderRecord))
                     .doOnError(e -> log.error("Send failed", e))
                     .last();

    }

}
```

What I can't grasp in my mind is what exactly is the difference between calling `this.sendMessage` as `.map` vs `.flatMap` from the outer pipeline, **so what for the explanation that map applying synchronous transformation to the emitted element if my synchronous function is not really doing anything synchronous apart from basic fields fetch?**

Here Kafka sender is already reactive and async , so it doesn't matter which one I use? Is that correct assumption?

Is my code non-idiomatic?

Or for this particular it would be just a safe wrap of everything I am doing inside `.sendMessage` in `.flatMap` in case someone would add synchronous code in future, i.e. sugar-safety syntax.

My understanding is that `.map` will simply prepare pipeline in this case which returns Mono, and subscriber for outer calling pipeline will trigger entire domino effect, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I can't grasp in my mind is what exactly is the difference between calling this.sendMessage as .map vs .flatMap from the outer pipeline

`map()` applies a synchronous function (i.e. one "in-place" with no subscriptions or callbacks) and just returns the result as is. `flatMap()` applies an asynchronous transformer function, and unwraps the Publisher when done. So:

> My understanding is that .map will simply prepare pipeline in this case which returns Mono, and subscriber for outer calling pipeline will trigger entire domino effect, is that correct?

Yes, that's correct (if by "domino effect" you mean that the returning mono will be subscribed to and its result returned.)

> so what for the explanation that map applying synchronous transformation to the emitted element if my synchronous function is not really doing anything synchronous apart from basic fields fetch?

Quite simply, because that's what you've told it to do. There's nothing inherently asynchronous about *setting up* a publisher, just its execution once it's been subscribed to (which doesn't happen with a `map()` call.)